# Inner join em tabelas 1 - n

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados, entity-framework

Tenho duas tabelas: Veiculo e Imagens, onde um veículo pode ter n imagens.
Ao realizar um inner join recebo o seguinte resultado:
Veículo1-Enderecoimagem
Veículo1-Enderecoimagem
Veículo2-Enderecoimagem
Veículo2-Enderecoimagem
Veículo2-Enderecoimagem
Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira obter os resultados desta forma:
V1-Todas as Imagens do Veículo1
V2-Todas as Imagens do Veículo2

Estou desenvolvendo um projetinho em asp net mvc e gostaria de mandar esse ultimo resultado para minha view.
Existe algo que eu possa fazer para obter os dados desta maneira.

Comment: Vc esta usando json? Se vc estiver apenas cria um array para estruturar do jeito que vc quer e envia.

Comment: Poderia postar a parte do código em que vc recupera as informações do banco e a parte em que vai exibir na View?, assim fica mais fácil de entendermos o que está sendo feito

Comment: public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Veiculo.ToList());
        }

Comment: Coloque essas informações na perguntas... mas vamos lá.. na sua View ela é tipada de ICollection de Veiculo, certo? você pode fazer algo assim `@foreach (var imagem in item.Imagens)`. no caso ficaria foreach dentro de foreach, ou seja para cada linha de veiculo passaria uma lista de imagens desse veiculo

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que estou a perceber trata-se somente de um problema de ordenação?

Se todos os veiculos têm pelo menos uma imagem, deve ser usado um `inner join` e no final da query um `order by` pelo id/nome/etc do veiculo.

Se um veiculo pode não ter uma imagem então deveria ser usado o `left join` para apanhar os casos dos veículos sem imagem. Aqui usaria também um `order by` pelo id/nome/etc do veiculo.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: O que eu realmente gostaria era que aparecesse o veículo com suas respectivas imagens em uma só linha e não em várias linhas.
Tem como?

Comment: Nesse caso https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855764/ms-sql-one-to-many-relationship-need-to-return-single-row